# How to fix this "conflicts: 1 shift/reduce"

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I write a grammar to parse velocity, It has a conflict at "if elseif else"

the flex file:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "context.h"
#include "bool.h"
#include "vtl4.tab.h"
%}
INT ([0-9]*)
%%
{INT} {return INTEGER;}
">" {return yytext[0];}
"(" {return yytext[0];}
")" {return yytext[0];}
"in" {return IN;}
"#foreach" {return FOREACH;}
"#end" {return END;}
"#if" {return IF;}
"#else" {return ELSE;}
"#elseif" {return ELSEIF;}
[^ \t] {yylval.string = yytext;return CONTENT;}
[ \t] {}
%%
```

the bison file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bool.h"
#include "parser.h"
#include "context.h"
#include "vtl4.tab.h"

extern FILE * yyin;
extern FILE * yyout;
extern int yylex();
extern int yywrap();
%}

%union {
struct simpleNode *ast;
double d;
int i;
bool b;
char* string;
struct symbol *sym;
}

%token <string> CONTENT NAME

%token IF ELSEIF ELSE END HASH DOLLAR PARENTHESIS PARENTHESIS_CLOSE LOGIC_EQUAL NEWLINE   INTEGER GL
%token FOREACH IN
%type <ast> stmts stmt

%nonassoc ELSEIF
%nonassoc ELSE

%%
stmts
: stmt{}
| stmts stmt{}
;

stmt:CONTENT {}
|directive {printf("stmt ---directive\n");}
|INTEGER {}
;

directive:FOREACH '(' exp ')' stmts END {printf("directive ---foreach\n");}
|if {printf("directive ---if\n");}
;

if:IF '(' cond ')' stmts END {printf("if\n");}
|IF '(' cond ')' stmts ELSE stmts END {printf("if else end\n");}
|IF '(' cond ')' stmts elseif END {printf("if elseif end\n");}
|IF '(' cond ')' stmts elseif ELSE stmts END {printf("if elseif ... else end\n");}
;

elseif:ELSEIF '(' cond ')' stmts {printf("one elseif\n");}
|elseif elseif {printf("Mul elseif\n");}
;

cond:INTEGER '>' INTEGER {printf("cond\n");}

exp:INTEGER IN INTEGER {printf("exp\n");}


%%
int main(){
FILE *src;
src = fopen("test.vm","r");
yyin = src;
yyparse();
fclose(src);
return 1;
}

int yywrap(){
return 1;
}
```

the output file says:

```
State 34 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
...
state 34

12 elseif: . ELSEIF '(' cond ')' stmts
13       | . elseif elseif  [ELSEIF, ELSE, END]
13       | elseif . elseif  [ELSEIF, ELSE, END]
13       | elseif elseif .  [ELSEIF, ELSE, END]

 ELSEIF  shift, and go to state 25

 ELSEIF    [reduce using rule 13 (elseif)]
 $default  reduce using rule 13 (elseif)

 elseif  go to state 34
```

I look up some information，and add priority levels for ELSE and ELSEIF,but isn't fix it.Please help me! maybe I don't understand the priority level mechanism very well

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how the language you wish to parse is intended to work, so this has to be a guess, but your problem might be here:

```
elseif : ELSEIF '(' cond ')' stmts
   | elseif elseif
   ;
```

An elseif can consist of two elsifs after each other. So if you have three elseifs, should they be grouped as **((elseif elseif) elseif)** or as **(elseif (elseif elseif))**? Bison doesn't know, and reports a conflict.

Another thing is that it is much simpler to understand and work with the grammar if you work with just the grammar, and not lots of other code. A minimal compilable, and more readably formatted, version of your Bison file looks like this (assuming I haven't made any mistakes in editing):

```
%token IF ELSEIF ELSE END INTEGER FOREACH IN

%nonassoc ELSEIF
%nonassoc ELSE

%%

stmts : stmt
      | stmts stmt
      ;

stmt: directive | INTEGER ;

directive : FOREACH '(' exp ')' stmts END
          | if
          ;

if : IF '(' cond ')' stmts END
   | IF '(' cond ')' stmts ELSE stmts END
   | IF '(' cond ')' stmts elseif END
   | IF '(' cond ')' stmts elseif ELSE stmts END
   ;

elseif : ELSEIF '(' cond ')' stmts
       | elseif elseif
       ;

cond : INTEGER '>' INTEGER ;

exp : INTEGER IN INTEGER ;

%%
```

I suggest this new grammar, which doesn't give any shift/reduce conflicts.

**EDIT:** I removed the %nonassoc precedence specifications, since they are not needed. You are using a syntax with an END for each IF, so you don't have the if-if-else conflict that you get in C-like grammars, and which you can remove by specifying precedences.

```
%token IF ELSEIF ELSE END INTEGER FOREACH IN

%%

stmts : stmt
      | stmts stmt
      ;

stmt: directive | INTEGER ;

directive : FOREACH '(' exp ')' stmts END
          | if
          ;

if : IF '(' cond ')' stmts END
   | IF '(' cond ')' stmts ELSE stmts END
   | IF '(' cond ')' stmts elseifs END
   | IF '(' cond ')' stmts elseifs ELSE stmts END
   ;

elseifs : elseif | elseifs elseif ;

elseif : ELSEIF '(' cond ')' stmts
       ;

cond : INTEGER '>' INTEGER ;

exp : INTEGER IN INTEGER ;

%%
```

Comment: Thank for your detailed answer.It work well.You let me understand so much,thank you.I will study it even more serious and I'm sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the various documentations and other SO questions about conflicts?  You should.  You'll see that your problem has nothing to do with `ELSE` (the output section you quote does not mention it in the conflict!).

Your grammar

```
elseifs: "#elseif" | elseifs elseifs
```

is obviously ambiguous.  Try

```
elseifs: "#elseif" | elseifs "#elseif"
```

or possibly

```
elseifs: | elseifs "#elseif"
```